# How to remove anything enclosed in : from a text?

Tags: bash, awk

I have a text which includes multiple substrings like `:xxx:` which should be removed using awk. The `xxx`-part could be any string but cannot contain white spaces or line breaks.

Here is an example text:

```
This is sample text:hello:
It might include normal colons like : or: that have to remain. :hello-world:
```

The command should turn that text into:

```
This is sample text 
It might include normal colons like : or: that have to remain.
```

My pathetic attempt:

```
awk '{gsub(":.*:","")}1'
```

Comment: `:[^[:space:]:]+:` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kcSAoX/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/:[^ :]*://g' input_file
This is sample text
It might include normal colons like : or: that have to remain.
```

Using `awk`

```
$ awk '{gsub(/:[^ :]*:/,"")}1' input_file
This is sample text
It might include normal colons like : or: that have to remain.
```

Comment: The second one removes not just `:item:` but also any trailing text.

Comment: Why do you have `|` in the character class?

Answer (score 3):

`The xxx-part could be any string but cannot contain white spaces or line breaks`.

```
awk 'gsub(/:[^[:space:]]*:/,"") 1' file
This is sample text
It might include normal colons like : or: that have to remain.
```

For this requirement, you can use the character class `[:space:]` for space characters.

> These are: space, TAB, newline, carriage return, formfeed and vertical tab). See "POSIX character classes" here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Bracket-Expressions.html